# Finding Gapful number in javascript

Tags: javascript

> > A number is gapful if it is at least 3 digits long and is divisible by the number formed by stringing the first and last numbers together.
> >     The smallest number that fits this description is 100. First digit is
> >     1, last digit is 0, forming 10, which is a factor of 100. Therefore,
> >     100 is gapful.
>
> Create a function that takes a number n and returns the closest gapful
>   number (including itself). If there are 2 gapful numbers that are
>   equidistant to n, return the lower one.
>
> Examples gapful(25) ➞ 100
>
> gapful(100) ➞ 100
>
> gapful(103) ➞ 105

so to solve this i wrote the code that loops from the given number to greater than that and find out if it is or not by

```
function getFrequency(array){
    var i=array
    while(i>=array){
        let a=i.toString().split('')
        let b=a[0]+a[a.length-1]
        b= +b
        if(i%b==0) return i
        i++
    }
}
console.log(getFrequency(103))
```

Thats fine but what if the gapful number is less than the number passed in the function ?
like if i pass 4780 the answer is 4773 so in my logic how do i check simultaneoulsy smaller and greater than the number passed ?

I am only looping for the numbers greater than the number provided in function

Comment: you can use recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take separate functions, one for a check if a number is a *gapful* number and another to get left and right values and for selecting the closest number.

```js
function isGapful(n) {
    if (n < 100) return false;
    var temp = Array.from(n.toString());
    return n % (temp[0] + temp[temp.length - 1]) === 0;    
}

function getClosestGapful(n) {
    var left = n,
        right = n;

    while (!isGapful(right)) right++;

    if (n < 100) return right;

    while (!isGapful(left)) left--;

    return n - left <= right - n
        ? left
        : right;
}

console.log(getClosestGapful(25));   //  100
console.log(getClosestGapful(100));  //  100
console.log(getClosestGapful(103));  //  105
console.log(getClosestGapful(4780)); // 4773
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate between subtracting and adding. Start at 0, then check -1, then check +1, then check -2, then check +2, etc:

```js
const gapful = (input) => {
  let diff = 0; // difference from input; starts at 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...
  let mult = 1; // always 1 or -1
  while (true) {
    const thisNum = input + (diff * mult);
    const thisStr = String(thisNum);
    const possibleFactor = thisStr[0] + thisStr[thisStr.length - 1];
    if (thisNum % possibleFactor === 0) {
      return thisNum;
    }
    mult *= -1;
    if (mult === 1) {
      diff++;
    }
  }
};
console.log(
  gapful(100),
  gapful(101),
  gapful(102),
  gapful(103),
  gapful(104),
  gapful(105),
  gapful(4780),
);
```